# @ServletSecurity Username

Tags: java, security, glassfish

I'm using

```
@ServletSecurity(
@HttpConstraint(transportGuarantee = ServletSecurity.TransportGuarantee.CONFIDENTIAL,rolesAllowed = {"CalendarUser"}))
```

to restrict access to my application. How can I obtain the name of the user in the servlet? With

```
String username = (String)session.getAttribute("username");
```

I'm receiving NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The username is accessible from HttpServletRequest interface via getRemoteUser. Also the full user principal is available via getUserPrincipal.

```
String username = request.getRemoteUser();
```